# How to check contain only characters + space and `p` using regex

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to check to contain only characters + space and `<p>` nodes inside `<used>`.

Input:

```
<root>
  <used><p>String 1</p></used>
  <used>string 2<p>string 3</p></used>
  <used>string 4</used>
  <used><image>aaa.jpg</image>para</used>
```

The output should be:

```
<ans>
  <abc>string 1</abc>
  <abc>string 4</abc>
</ans>
```

Tried code:

```
<ans>
  <abc>
    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl: when test="getCode/matches(text(),'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')">
          <xsl:text>text()</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  </abc>
</ans>
```

My tried code is not working as I am expecting. How can I fix this? Thank you. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: From your description, three elements match your criteria: 1,2 and 4. All of them *"contain only characters + space and <p> nodes"*.

Comment: @zx485 `<used>string 2<p>string 3</p></used>` here.`<used>` contain `<p>` and text. So it should not be transformed. only text or only `p` not for both.

Comment: The additional info helped. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT-2.0 stylesheet to get the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Handle the <root> element -->
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <ans>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="used" />
      </ans>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Create <abc> elements for every matching element -->
    <xsl:template match="used[not(*) and matches(text(),'^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$')] | used[not(text()) and matches(p/text(),'^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$')]/p">
      <abc><xsl:copy-of select="text()" /></abc>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove all spurious text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ans>
   <abc>String 1</abc>
   <abc>string 4</abc>
</ans>
```